# my datagridview2 shows the same data with my datagridview1

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have this 2 datagridview one is in form 2 and the other is in from3. And I have this log in in form 1.

If a user logs in and his position is pharmacist he will then proceed to form2 and datagridview1 should display all the data of my table pharmacy in my database. After that he logged out.

If a new user logged for example the admin he will then proceed to form 3 and datagridview2 should show him data of the list of employees from table employees in my database.

The problem is datagridview2 shows the lists of all the medicines which is the content of my datagridview1.

here is my code

here is my code for my datagridview1

```
Call main()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM PHARMACY"
        con.Open()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
        cmd = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(mytable)
        MyBind.DataSource = mytable
        MyGrid.DataSource = MyBind
        con.Close()

and here is my code for my datagridview2

        Call main()
        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ASTATUS = 'Pending' "
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
        cmd = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Fill(mytable)
        myBind3.DataSource = mytable
        myGrid3.DataSource = myBind3
        con.close()
```

Comment: Check if you are calling your sql function for both datagridview or post your code please.

Comment: here is my code for my datagridview1

Comment: why don't you try differ the name of your call for the 1st and the 2nd
I mean for the 1st put call main() and for the second put call second()

Comment: oh main() is my sql connection in my module.. i have solved my problem i declared a datable in each form that has datagridview. and also thank you :))